# How to modify the default tile map collider 2D Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm new at unity 2D,I crated this scene so far, But I had problem with the Tile map 2D collider (that comes by default when I created a grid and used a palette to create this simple scene) : [image]

I want to edit this collider, for example the true now is behaving as an obstacle, and I don't want that, so I need to remove it or something like that if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can "remove" the collider from specific tiles by selecting them in the assets and select `Collider Type` -> `None` (See [`TileMapCollider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TilemapCollider2D.html)

> The Tilemap Collider 2D component does not generate any Collider shapes for this Tile.

[image]